# specificy gpu devices failed when using tensorflow c++ api

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, gpu

I trained my tf model in python:

```
  with sv.managed_session(master='') as sess:
    with tf.device("/gpu:1"):#my systerm has 4 nvidia cards
```

and use the command line to abstract the model:

```
  freeze_graph.py --clear_devices False
```

and during test phase, I set the device as follow:

```
  tensorflow::graph::SetDefaultDevice("/gpu:1", &tensorflow_graph);
```

but someting is wrong:

```
  ould not create Tensorflow Graph: 
  Invalid argument: Cannot assign a device to node '.../RNN_backword/while/Enter': 
  Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/gpu:1' 
  because no devices matching that specification are registered in this process; 
  available devices: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
```

so,how can I use gpu i correctly??

anyone could help??

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you're using a version of TensorFlow without GPU support enabled?  If you're building a binary you may need to add additional BUILD rules from //tensorflow that enable GPU support.  Also ensure you enabled GPU support when running configure.

**EDIT**: Can you file a bug on TF's github issues with:

1) your BUILD rule

2) much more of your code so we can see how you're building your model and creating your session

3) how you ran configure

While this API is not yet marked "public"; we want to see if there's indeed a bug you are running into so we can fix it.

Comment: thanks a lot,and your advice is helpful,bazel build --config=cuda & change the cc_library‘s deps works